# Speed up image/mask to numpy array in Python with AMD Radeon eGPU (Metal) on OSX

Tags: python, gpu

To speed up training Keras models I use an external AMD Radeon RX Vega 56 eGPU with my MacBook Pro with PlaidML, in Metal mode. However, I often have to add images or masks to numpy arrays first for training. For this, I cannot seem to manage to use the external eGPU.

**Does anybody know if this process (example code below) can be done on the external eGPU as well?**

*Example piece of code that I want to speed up with the external eGPU:*

```
train_image = []
for index, row in train_df.iterrows():
    path = Path(train_path + row["ImageId"])
    img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(img_height, img_width, channels))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = img/255
    print(index, row["ImageId"],row['Category'], img.shape)
    train_image.append(img)
train_img = np.array(train_image)
```